# SELECT Statement in Joomla TMPL default.php file

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I'm developing a Joomla component. Where I have years, months and tour dates.

The idea is to have

2011 2012 2013 2014 (links) and let's say 2011 is active. below I have

**sept, 2011**

concert in sept #1;
   concert in sept #2;
   concert in sept #3;

**oct, 2011**

concert in oct #1;
   concert in oct #2;
   concert in oct #3;

**nov, 2011**

concert in nov #1;
   concert in nov #2;
   concert in nov #3;

I guess you can understand the display structure.

I have 1 table, and on my custom made page I would handle that with no problem. but I'm developing it on Joomla, so I'm a bit confused.

I have 1 function getYEAR that displays years and in Tmpl default.php I have foreach.

Now I created another function getMonth that displays months and it looks like this:

```
                $now = date('Y'); 
        $year = JRequest::getInt('year',  $now);
        $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT MONTH( date ), #__concert_month.monthname 
                FROM #__concert_info
                JOIN #__concert_month ON #__concert_month.id = MONTH( date ) 
                WHERE YEAR( date ) = {$year} AND date >= CURDATE( ) 
                ORDER BY MONTH( date )";
        $db->setQuery( $query );
        $this->_month = $db->loadObjectList();

        return $this->_month;
```

And it's fine. but the **problem** is that I want to SELECT tour places according to months, like I described above Month -> concerts, Month->concerts

Normally I would do

```
    SElECT smth1
    foreach1 (smth1 as smt1)

    echo Monthname  $id=smth1

    SELECT smth2 WHERE MONTH( date ) = $id
    foreach2(smth2 as smt2)
    endforeach2


    endforeach1
```

How can I have SELECT inside FOREACH in tmpl->default.php? Or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can put `SELECT` directly into the `tmpl->default.php` file. I guess I was wrong somewhere yesterday, today it worked.

I still don't like the idea of putting `SELECT` into `default.php`, though (I'd prefer to put it in models, the way it should be).